# c# how to check in 2d matrix if all numbers above or below the slant are equel to 0?

Tags: c#, matrix

i was requested to write a program that check in 2d of 6x6 if all numbers above or below the slant are equel to 0,
so far i created a simple matrix to help me figure it out, but i got stuck in the conditon and im not sure what to do..
exmaple:

[exmaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsylD.png)

---

my code so far:(got stack in the condition)

```
int[,] matrix = new int[6, 6]
            {
              {1,0,0,0,0,0},
              {0,2,0,0,0,0},
              {0,0,3,0,0,0},
              {0,0,0,4,0,0},
              {0,0,0,0,5,0},
              {0,0,0,0,0,6},
            };

        int row, col;
        int zeroabove = 0;
        int zerobelow = 0;

        for (row = 0; row < 6; row++)
        {
            for(col = 0; col < 6; col++)
            {
                if (row == 0 || col == 0)
                {
                  //idk what to put here  
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "above the slant" means but I think if you are able to translate that into an exact specification your problem will mostly be solved. For example, perhaps it means "All cells where col < (6 - row)", in which case it is trivial to write an `if` expression or a `where` delegate to match.

Comment: ahm, for bove the slant its just the same as below, when all numbers above it are 0's or all numbers below the slant are 0'...
one of these condition has to be exist or not at all..
but for the code you gave me we did not got to the break option yet in the class, is there something else i can use ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a code like this:

```
int row, col;
bool isZeroAbove = true;
bool isZeroBelow = true;

for (row = 0; row < 6 && (isZeroAbove || isZeroBelow); row++)
    for (col = 0; col < 6 && (isZeroAbove || isZeroBelow); col++)
        if (matrix[row, col] != 0)
            if (row > col)
                isZeroBelow = false;
            else if (row < col)
                isZeroAbove = false;
```

Comment: Why'd you remove the accolades? Keeping them makes code easier to read.

Comment: @JannickBreunis Yes, you are right, it may result in a bug, however, I personally prefer to remove curly braces in implementing a simple logic.

Comment: i see what you did here, i tought almost the same i just having issue to apply it in code..
thanks a lot

Comment: how using the != can help me check the answer ?
the condition is that all cells above or below has to be 0's, like how i draw in my code above, can you explain ?

Comment: @Moshiko Firstly, I assume that all matrix elements above the main diagonal are equal to 0. Then if an element != 0, the above zero assumptions is false. we need only one element not being equal to zero in above and below.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you want to check certain cells in the matrix depending on their coordinates. For example, if you are trying to check all cells that are above the diagonal formed by the line `x = y` then you wish to only check cells where `x > y`.

This sort of thing is pretty easy with LINQ, but LINQ doesn't work with two-dimensional arrays very well. So to make this possible, we need an extension method that will select over a two-dimensional array and return the coordinates and value for each cell. This can be accomplished with a simple extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public class MatrixItem<T>
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
    static public IEnumerable<MatrixItem<T>> Flatten<T>(this T[,] source)
    {
        for (int i = source.GetLowerBound(0); i <= source.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = source.GetLowerBound(1); j <= source.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                yield return new MatrixItem<T> { X = j, Y = i, Value = source[i, j] };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When used with a two-dimensional array, this method will return a one-dimensional enumerable containing every cell along with its coordinates in an object called `MatrixItem`. The coordinates and value are exposed as separate properties.

Now that we can easily query against the matrix, the solution to your problem is very simple:

```
bool zeroAbove = !matrix.Flatten()
    .Where(item => item.X > item.Y)
    .Any(item => item.Value != 0);
```

Comment: the only problem that i have to apply it using 2d array, 
in the class we just started and the teacher gave has quations that has to be apply using 2d array, that is way i asked that